# Compare validator is getting active on any click

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, comparevalidator

```
 <asp:ComboBox ID="ddlto" runat="server" IncrementalFilteringMode="StartsWith"
                DataSourceID="XmlDatasource1" TextField="name" ValueField="name"
                Width="100%" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name" MaxLength="0" style="display: inline;" 
                                                AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" 
                                                onselectedindexchanged="ddlto_SelectedIndexChanged" />

                                        </td></br>

                          <asp:CompareValidator ID="cm1" runat="server" Operator="NotEqual" Type="string" ControlToValidate="ddlfrom" ControlToCompare="ddlto" ErrorMessage="The 'Departure City' and 'Destination City' cannot be same. Please re-type." ForeColor="red" 
BackColor="yellow" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"> </asp:CompareValidator
```

It is working properly for that page but when i am clicknig on any other button of that page to redirect to other page again the same messaage of compare validator is printing and i cannot redirect to another page.Means i have 3 pages bus,train and flight when i am removing this compare validator code then i am able to redirext the pages..but when i place these code..in my asp page then, when i click on flight button to redirect to the flight page,it is showing the same message as i have typd in compare validator code.it is not redirecting.PLZZ HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ValidationGroup` property to validator and button which should do validation

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="ddlto" ... ValidationGroup="MyValidation"... />

<asp:Button ID="MyBtn" ... ValidationGroup="MyValidation"... />
```

Just make sure, that validator and button have same group.

Comment: u mean in my .cs file?

Comment: one more doubt i got.when my fields are empty means i have not entered anything in the given fields then also by clicking on save button its displaying the message of compare validator..why is that..?

Comment: Not sure, i can't reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

use vlaidation group property

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cm1" runat="server" Operator="NotEqual" Type="string"
ControlToValidate="ddlfrom" ControlToCompare="ddlto" ErrorMessage="The 'Departure City'     
and 'Destination City' cannot be same. Please re-type." ForeColor="red" 
BackColor="yellow" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"> </asp:CompareValidator>
```

vlaidationgroup="abc"

here add this prprety along with other properties and give same to that button also then it will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation about the **ValidationGroup** attribute for Form Elements.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx

The basic idea is to group all the elements you want to be validated when you click a specific button, by identifying them with the same **ValidationGroup** value